# MS Access database trouble

Tags: database, ms-access-2010

I have an access database that has been used for many years, converted from Access 2000 to 2007 and was fine. In the last couple weeks it has been doing strange things!

There is a form for 'editing' a record. When the user clicked on the button to open this form, a small white box appeared and said 'Record Deleted'.

After that, the database was corrupted. I support this database and I can not even get into it in design view. When I try to open it (holding the shift key down while opening it), it takes a while, then it displays the Access design page that has the 'blank database' icon and to the right it lists the frequent opened databases.

So, I can't even get the to objects. The only option I had was to restore from a previous night backup. This meant the users lost all their work for the day. Today, one week later, it has happened again. All the users work was lost because I had to restore from backup.

I don't know where to begin to trouble shoot this since I can not get into it in design view when it has become corrupted. Looking for any suggestions to debug this. I can use a copy of the database I had restored.

Thanks

Comment: Thnx Marc_s (Shame on me)

Answer (score 0):

As a first and most important suggestion. You should split your database.You can do this from the database tools tab on top. By doing this you will have a seperate back end independat of the front end and your client will not loose any data as if they get the error / corrupted database it would not affect the data secured in the backend

Second I havent had the exact same error but in the past I have faced instances where the forms just dont work. a recommendation i read somewhere was to create a new blank form and copy over the elements from this form onto that and delete this form. I doubt if there is any problem with the VBA but it would be worth compiling the code to check.

Apologies if this does not help much, but I hope the first suggestions helps protect your client data in the instance your database crashes.

Answer (score 0):

First, check if any automated VBA code or macro is running on OnOpen, OnLoad, OnCurrent, AfterUpdate, OnDirty, etc. events of the troubleshooting forms. Simply open the VBA window and look at code on the specific form's module. Or in the case of macros, open form in design view and check the Event tab of Property Sheet (and the same for specific buttons, textboxes, etc.). There may be DoCmd.RunCommands occurring when users interact with form controls.

Also, if you find yourself unable to open forms or deal with a corrupted database, consider beginning with a blank Access .accdb file and import all objects from the previous Access 2000 .mdb file. And if specific controls don't function properly, recreate them as needed.

As mentioned above, split your database between BackEnd (only tables) and FrontEnd (forms, queries, macros, modules) which prevents corruption, efficiently runs systems as only data is sent across the network and not whole application items, and overall fosters a better multi-user environment. Each user can have copies of the FE on their local machines but all will connect to one BE on a shared network. To help, Access 2007-2013 has a button for this on the Ribbon under Database Tools.